# Lambda and colon in while statement for PHP?

Tags: php

What does the below code mean (it's a lambda in the while-statement, then a colon after)? Coming from JavaScript, I have no idea what that means or even how to search for that. Can anyone help explain this?

```
while ($query->have_posts()): $query->the_post();
```

Btw I got this from WordPress but is the syntax pure PHP?

Comment: Where exactly is the lambda?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a less-common while structure:

```
while (condition):
    doSomething();
endwhile;
```

This is not how things are traditionally done, but it is valid syntax.  See [while loop syntax](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.while.php) for more details, as well as [alternative control syntax](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php).

Answer (score 1):

It is an [alternative syntax](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php) for control structures.

Answer (score 1):

In general, this:

```
while (expression) :
  //actions
endwhile;
```

is the same as this:

```
while (expression) {
  //actions
}
```

which is what you're probably used to.
The bracketted expression `$query->havePosts()` is just the condition of the `while`, and the sentence after the colon is the first line within the `while`.